# How to force 1920x1080 resolution - Fedora 16, VMPlayer, 9800GTX

Tags: fedora, xorg, gnome3, vmware

I'm running F16 on VMplayer, I don't think the drivers I'm using are for my nvidia card. I'm getting a max resolution of 1280*768.

My card is EVGA 9800GTX+ --- I need instructions on how to change my xorg config (I'm assuming that's the problem).

---

In gnome display settings I'm now able to set my resolution to 1920x1080

After forcing `vmware` driver in xorg.conf
My xorg.conf looks like this atm;

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "device0"
    VendorName "VMware SVGA II Adapter"
    BoardName "VMware SVGA II Adapter"
    Driver "vmware"
    Option "SWcursor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "screen0"
    Device "device1"
    Monitor "monitor1"
    DefaultColorDepth 24
Subsection "Display"
    Depth 8
    Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubsection
Subsection "Display"
    Depth 15
    Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubsection
Subsection "Display"
    Depth 16
    Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubsection
Subsection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubsection
EndSection
```

After logging in my resolution changes to 1920x1080
The only setting being picked up by xorg.conf is driver `vmware`
At login screen my resolution is 1024x768

Comment: You have installed the VMware Tools? They are needed if you want to get higher resolutions.

Comment: @RenanBirckPinheiro, yes I ran ran vmware-tools without problems, but I'll run the script again.

Comment: It is as Renan says. I too am using Fedora (version 15) or VMWare Fusion. The resolution immediately maxed out to full screen after a successful installation of VMWare tools. Do a google search on what you need to do to properly install it.

Comment: @seljuq70 Ok, I'm trying it again at the moment, hope your both right, thanks.

Comment: Reinstalled vmware-tools and rebooted to no avail.

Comment: @903 Have you looked at the following sites: http://www.sysprobs.com/fedora-14-vmware-install-vmware-tools-fedora-14 or http://www.crazyhawt.com/2010/01/25/quick-guide-installing-vmware-tools-with-fedora-12/ Also, when you make a comment, place a "@username" in the beginning to notify others. I only went back to this question to see if it worked out for you.

Comment: @seljuq70 Sorry about that, still pretty new to the way things work on stack... Thanks for the links, I actually looked at the sysprob guide, but no luck. I ended up getting what I wanted, basic knowledge on how to config apache and set up permissions. So I moved scratched F16, and installed ubuntu server. Maybe someone who runs into a problem with F16 and vmware-tools will follow up on your links, so I'll leave it up

Comment: @903 Yeah, the truth is that I took several attempts to get vmware-tools going on Fedora. This OS doesn't exactly have a reputation for stability. In fact, I've somehow gotten a corrupted filesystem and had to run fsck thrice already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially Solved, although vmware tools did not install properly, the xorg drivers for vmware were installed but xorg.conf wasn't pointing to those drivers.

I changed the driver from default `vesa` to `vmware`..
full list of resolutions is now available under gnome settings.

**My xorg.conf at the moment;**

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Display0"
    Driver     "vmware"
EndSection
```

Make sure you have the driver installed;

```
yum install xorg-x11-drv-vmware
```

---

Hope that helps someone who comes across the same problem.
GDM still boots with 640x486, but after login gnome settings take priority and display my resolution of 1920x1080. I gave up on trying to completely fix my problem, and removed F16 and installed Ubuntu Server 11.10. I also tried Ubuntu 11.10 desktop x86, which was trouble free when it came down to installing vmware-tools.

Hopefully this will help those having problems with vmware-tools.

Also helpful links thanks to seljuq70

http://www.sysprobs.com/fedora-14-vmware-install-vmware-tools-fedora-14

http://www.crazyhawt.com/2010/01/25/quick-guide-installing-vmware-tools-with-fedora-12/

---

I haven't tried this but the problem with the GDM resolution probably has to do with a setting in grub.conf, I read about it after I had already removed F16 from vmplayer.

But for those who have problems with pre-login resolution, may want to look at this.
http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem after installing VMware.
My system is:

```
root@:~#uname -a
FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE # 0 r255898: Thu Sep 26 22:50:31 UTC 2013 root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC amd64
```

OK.Solution:
go to the **"/etc/X11/xorg.conf"**

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "VMware SVGA"
    Driver "vmware"
EndSection
```

change it to

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "VMware SVGA"
    Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

Next, look for

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen 1"
    Device "VMware SVGA"
    Monitor "vmware"
    # Don't specify DefaultColorDepth unless you know what you're
    ...
EndSection
```

add **"DefaultColorDepth 24"**

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen 1"
    Device "VMware SVGA"
    Monitor "vmware"
    DefaultColorDepth 24
    # Don't specify DefaultColorDepth unless you know what you're
    ...
EndSection
```

Next, look for section **"display"** where **"Depht 24"** and change the value to the desired resolution
Example:

```
Subsection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
    ViewPort 0 0
EndSubsection
```

save **"/etc/X11/xorg.conf"**
leave.Next

```
root@:~#startx
```

leave.Next

```
root@:~#cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|grep 1920x1080
```

will show something like this

```
(II) vmwlegacy (0): Modeline "vmware-default-1920x1080" x1.0 2.60 1920 1921 1922 2402 1080 1081 1082 1083 (1.1 kHz)
```

Write down where or whether these values:

```
"1920x1080" 2.60 1920 1921 1922 2402 1080 1081 1082 1083
```

Later, they will come in handy. OK

Then again, edit the **"/etc/X11/xorg.conf"**

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "VMware SVGA"
    Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

change it to

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "VMware SVGA"
    Driver "vmware"
EndSection
```

Next, look for

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "vmware"
    VendorName "VMware, Inc"
    HorizSync 1-10000
    VertRefresh 1-10000
EndSection
```

add item **"ModeLine"** and insert there
our recorded value (the output of **Xorg.0.log**)

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "vmware"
    VendorName "VMware, Inc"
    ModeLine "1920x1080" 2.60 1920 1921 1922 2402 1080 1081 1082 1083
    HorizSync 1-10000
    VertRefresh 1-10000
EndSection
```

save **"/etc/X11/xorg.conf"**

```
root@:~#startx
```

rejoice! =)